# Access Images from Folder in Assets.xcassets in Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

How do I access Images from a folder located in Assets.xcassets in Xcode?
    I know how to access images located in the Assets.xcassets folder itself, but not sure how to access stuff from a specific folder located in Assets.xcassets.

I am using the following code to access images from the Assets.xcassets:

```
// seperate file for image data containing a struct 
    struct Images {
    var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1.jpg")!]
}

// creating an instance of the image data swift file struct in view controller file  
    var myImages = Images() 

// setting the image property of UIImage in storyboard 
    UImageInstance.image = Images.images[1]
```

How do I access the images if they are stored in a folder inside Assets.xcassets? instead of just being in Assets.xcassets.

Comment: Are you talking about **Right Click on Assets.xcassets  and click on Show in Finder**

Comment: Never Mind :) It's the same as accessing elements in the Assets.xcassests folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same :) As accessing elements in the Assets.xcassests